# about an example in Linux find man page

Tags: linux, find

The following example in Linux find man page doesn't seem to work:

```
   find repo/ -exec test -d {}/.svn \; -or \
   -exec test -d {}/.git \; -or -exec test -d {}/CVS \; \
   -print -prune

   Given the following directory of projects and their associated SCM
   administrative directories, perform an efficient search for the
   projects' roots:

   repo/project1/CVS
   repo/gnu/project2/.svn
   repo/gnu/project3/.svn
   repo/gnu/project3/src/.svn
   repo/project4/.git

   In this example, -prune prevents unnecessary descent into directories
   that have already been discovered (for example we do not search
   project3/src because we already found project3/.svn), but ensures
   sibling directories (project2 and project3) are found.
```

The find displays no output. Does anybody know why? 
I noticed this find had no tests since "-exec" clause are actions not tests (can an action be a test too?). and since "-or" has lower precedence than implied "-and" between the last "-exec" and "-print", the logic expressed in the command line doesn't seem to be what it was intended to be.

```
>uname -r
 2.6.32-131.0.15.el6.x86_64
>pwd
 /var/tmp
>mkdir -p repo/project1
>mkdir -p repo/gnu/project2
>mkdir -p repo/gnu/project3/src
>mkdir -p repo/project4
>touch repo/project1/CVS
>touch repo/gnu/project2/.svn
>touch repo/gnu/project3/.svn
>touch repo/gnu/project3/src/.svn
>touch repo/project4/.git

>find repo
repo
repo/project4
repo/project4/.git
repo/gnu
repo/gnu/project3
repo/gnu/project3/src
repo/gnu/project3/src/.svn
repo/gnu/project3/.svn
repo/gnu/project2
repo/gnu/project2/.svn
repo/project1
repo/project1/CVS

>find repo/ -exec test -d {}/.svn \; -or -exec test -d {}/.git \; -or -exec test -d {}/CVS \; -print -prune
>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example is bad. It's doing

```
find -exec command1 \; -or -exec command2 \; -or -exec command3 \; -print -prune
```

Which is equivilent to

```
find -exec command1 \; -or -exec command2 \; -or -exec command3 \; -and -print -and -prune
```

But since `-and` (`-a`) has higher presedence than `-or` (`-o`), the `-print` and `-prune` are only applied to `-command3`

[Bug Report](http://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?47482)

*About `test`. You're confusing `tests` in the find man page, which is simply what they call a specific groups of their operators, with the [test](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/test.html) command that's used above.*

Answer (score 0):

What man find writes about exec in the first sentence should answer your question:

> ```
>    -exec command ;
>           Execute command; **true if 0 status** is returned.
> ```

Comment: so -exec can also act as a test. but the command output is empty...which means it not properly formulated.

Comment: All the execs contain tests for directories and none of them ends with success (0).

Comment: @GombaiSándor This doesn't answer the question.